# Example of Non Uniform Integrability

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Consider a family of functions $\{f_n\}$, where $f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0 }$, and a probability measure on $X$.

Please provide an example in which all functions $f_n$ are integrable but not [uniformly integrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability) in the "probability sense":

$$ \lim_{c \rightarrow \infty} \ \sup_n \mathbb{E} \{ f_n \mid {f_n \geq c} \} = 0$$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37305) there is an example, but the family is uniformly integrale in the "probability sense".

Comment: I suspect you want to add a condition like $f_n$ converges in some sense.  Otherwise you could take $f_n=n$ (for instance).  It is a theorem that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ in probability, then $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ if and only if the family is uniformly integrable.

Comment: I'm not completely clear about your comment: I don't want to exclude the case of having a finite number of functions in the family.

Can you provide a link of the theorem are you talking about?

Comment: Any finite subset of $L^1$ is uniformly integrable.  My point was that one of the reasons uniformly integrable is a useful concept is it tells you when things that converge in probability converge in $L^1$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relations_to_convergence_of_random_variables or any measure theoretic intro to probability).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f_n = n 1_{A_n}$ where $\mu(A_n) = 1/n$.  (For instance, on $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, you could take $A_n = [0,\frac{1}{n}]$.)  I think this is the example that was intended in the linked answer, and it is *not* uniformly integrable in your sense (or any other).

Comment: I'm not completely clear on that. Let's apply the definition step by step: first we compute $\int_{f_n \geq c} f_n $.

This is equal to $0$ if $c>n$; equal to $1$ if $c \leq n$.

Taking the $\sup_n$ we have $1$ (independently from $c$) and also after taking $\lim_{c \rightarrow \infty}$.

So we have $1$ instead of $0$: NON U.I. 

Are these steps correct?

Comment: @Adam: Yes, you've got it.